# Load globalvariable raw data value in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

When I iterate GlobalVariable and use:

```
Constant *initializer = gv->getInitializer();
ConstantDataSequential *cdata = dyn_cast<ConstantDataSequential>(initializer);
const char *array=cdata->getRawDataValues().data()
```

to put them into a char array, I can modify the data like operating on a char array object.

However when I use `LoadInst` and `GetElementPtrInst` to get the element, I can not treat every element as the `char` type. The question is how can I achieve the same goal using llvm API.

Comment: Can you give some more information about what you actually are trying to achieve? `Load` and `GEP` instructions load data from some memory location. Unless the flow of the data is known, it's impossible for LLVM (or me, or you) to know what the value actually is.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know can we `load` the value in globalvariable and convert it into `char*` or `string` type.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not treat every element as the char type
>   Sorry, I just want to know can we load the value in globalvariable and convert it into char* or string

I suggest you take a look at [LLVM Language Reference Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) as well as the DragonBook since judging by your post history you pretty much have absolutely no idea about compiler internals yet.

As for your question, there is no such thing as char or string type at the LLVM IR Level and the `char*` or `string` is of type i8* usually at the IR level, which you could find out yourself by reading through the LLVM IR. Some combination of `LoadInst`,`GetElementPtr` and `BitCast` could achieve what you are trying to do.

On a side note, if you are trying to write StringEncryption passes which I believe is the case judging by your post history, take a look at [my open-source implementation](https://github.com/HikariObfuscator/Hikari/blob/release_60/lib/Transforms/Obfuscation/StringEncryption.cpp)  and hopefully you could learn a bit or so

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new to the LLVM and there are still many things I need to learn.